# How to handle multiple image upload in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

It's about two days I'm trying to upload images using Nodejs and Expressjs (4.0).

I tryed several middlewares so far, like: Formidable, Blueimp, Busboy, Multer...

With few of these I correctly saved a single image on a temporary folder but the problems comes when I try to upload multiple images.

So, my simple controller look like:

```
exports.postAccountImages = function(req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
    console.log(req.files);
  });
};
```

What I receive is always single Objects like:

```
{
  files: {
    // data...
  }
}
{
  files: {
    // data...
  }
}
```

But are not inside an array, so I can not manage all the files incoming using `for`.

I need to change the name to the images and save these on dynamic folder based on user.id name... but it seems to be too tricky.

I can do it one by one, but I wish to do that on multiple images.

Do you know a middleware or how to use correctly one of the ones I already tried to manage multiple files?

EDIT:

I used Dragzone for the client side.
Nothing special here, followed the initial tutorial:

Jade:

```
#uploader.fileInput
  h3 Drop your images here!
```

Js:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
        url: "/account/images", // Set the url
        autoQueue: true,
        paramName: "file",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        clickable: ".fileInput"
});
```

Comment: You might want to include what your upload form/code looks like on the client side.

Comment: Done, I followed a simple tutorial

Comment: Everything I try to do it limit my file uploads to 2. It seems like I can not upload more that 2 files per time...

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo Please add my answer as correct if you like it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this solves your question, this is my method to multiple upload file:

Nodejs :

```
router.post('/upload', function(req , res) {

var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var form = new multiparty.Form();
var fs = require('fs');

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {  
    var imgArray = files.imatges;


    for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        var newPath = './public/uploads/'+fields.imgName+'/';
        var singleImg = imgArray[i];
        newPath+= singleImg.originalFilename;
        readAndWriteFile(singleImg, newPath);           
    }
    res.send("File uploaded to: " + newPath);

});

function readAndWriteFile(singleImg, newPath) {

        fs.readFile(singleImg.path , function(err,data) {
            fs.writeFile(newPath,data, function(err) {
                if (err) console.log('ERRRRRR!! :'+err);
                console.log('Fitxer: '+singleImg.originalFilename +' - '+ newPath);
            })
        })
}
})
```

Make sure your has **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

I hope this gives you a hand ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves your question. 
How To Multiple Image upload using Nodejs And MongoDB

```
import formidable from 'formidable';
import multiparty from 'multiparty';
import _ from 'lodash'
import fs from 'fs'

async create(req,res){
    let form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.keepExtensions=true;
    form.parse(req,(err,field,files) => {
        if(err)
        {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:'Image Could Not Uploaded'
            })
        }

        // Multiple Image Store into Database
        let product = new Product(field)
        var imgArray = files.photo;
        var photoarray =  new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
            if(imgArray.size >= 1000000)  
            {
                res.status(401).json({
                    error:'Image is Less then 1 MB'
                })
            }  
            var newPath = './uploads/product/';
            var singleImg = imgArray[i];
            newPath+= Date.now()+'_'+singleImg.originalFilename;
            readAndWriteFile(singleImg, newPath);     
            photoarray.push(newPath)      
        }
        product.photo=photoarray;

        //Comma Separated Value Store into MongoDB
        var sizestr = field.size.toString()
        var text_arr = sizestr.split(',')
        var sizearray =  new Array();
        for(var i=0;i<text_arr.length;i++)
        {
            sizearray.push(text_arr[i])
        }
        product.size=sizearray;
        product.name=field.name.toString()

        product.save((err,result)=>{
            console.log(err)
            if(err){
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error:errorHandler(err)
                })
            }
            return res.json(result)
        })
    });
    function readAndWriteFile(singleImg, newPath) {

            fs.readFile(singleImg.path , function(err,data) {
                fs.writeFile(newPath,data, function(err) {
                    if (err) console.log('ERRRRRR!! :'+err);
                    console.log('Fitxer: '+singleImg.originalFilename +' - '+ newPath);
                })
            })
    }
}
```